# Answer accept indicator

Tags: script, answers

### About

With [Outdated Answers: accepted answer is now unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/outdated-answers-accepted-answer-is-now-unpinned-on-stack-overflow), I find that it would be nice to have an indicator. Some posts have multiple pages, and searching for the one post among many requires a little too much scrolling.

#### How it works

The script will check the timeline for an accept event. If it finds one, it will add a checkmark to the post title, as marked in red.

If this variable in the script is set to false:

```js
const addToTitle = false;
```

the script will instead add a button next to the sorting filters, as marked in pink.

Clicking on the checkmark / button will take you directly to the accepted post.

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Sites

Should work across the Stack Exchange network.
Note that the wording of the button isn't locale specific.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager & any browser running JavaScript.
Tested using Opera with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackAcceptedAnswerButton) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackAcceptedAnswerButton/StackAcceptedAnswerButton.user.js)

#### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.

Comment: wait... is that an actual question in the image?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE No, this is just like a mockup in order to show the userscript features.

Comment: Oh. I thought someone's mouse wheel scrolled so slowly that it took 11 hours to scroll a question.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE There were 4 pages of Answers on the post. It takes a while to go through them all.